# Automatic Bluetooth pairing with multiple adapter MAC address

Tags: ubuntu, bluetooth

On Ubuntu 12.04, we're trying to do some auto-pairing of hundred of bluetooth devices.

The easy way we found is to add an entry for each device to `/var/lib/bluetooth/11:22:33:44:55:66/pincodes` like so :

```
aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff 1234
```

Unfortunately, we don't know in advance what will be the MAC address of the bluetooth adapter (here 11:22:33:44:55:66). So we're looking for something that's separate of it (like `/var/lib/bluetooth/any/pincodes` ) ... or anything else that could automate the pairing.

ps: Of course the real pin code isn't 1234 but one per device. Otherwise that would be straightforward like it is for mouse and keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found a proper solution. Instead a pretty good workaround.

Since the users always use the same script to initiate traffic to their Bluetooth devices, I added a `sudo set_bt_pincodes.py` at the begining of that script.
This new file just fill all `/var/lib/bluetooth/*/pincodes` files that don't exist yet.

Additionally I had to add appropriate info to `/etc/sudoers` .

Et Voilà :)